# mysql how to mulitply some values in the same column but not others if it meets a condition

Tags: mysql, calculated-field

Is it possible to mulitply some values in the same column but not others if the value meets a certain condition? I don't want to create another column.

Query I am working with:

```
SELECT
    name ,
    ROUND(SUM(orderline_sales.amount * orderline_sales.price) * orders_sales.discount * customers.annual_discount) AS total_revenue
FROM
    orderline_sales 
        JOIN
    orders_sales  ON orders_sales.id = orderline_sales.orders_sales_id
        JOIN
    employee ON orders_sales.empoyee_id = employee.id
        JOIN 
    customers ON orders_sales.customer_id = customers.id
WHERE
    date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY employee.name
ORDER BY totale_omzet DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The orders_sales table contains a date attributetype and the orders_sales table has a 1:n cardinal relationship with orderline_sales. I only want to multiply the SUM result with customers.annual_discount if the YEAR of the order is higher than 2017. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CASE.

```
  SELECT 
     CASE WHEN YEAR > 2017 THEN
      ROUND(SUM(orderline_sales.amount * orderline_sales.price) * 
  orders_sales.discount * 
        customers.annual_discount)
   ELSE 
   (orderline_sales.price * orders_sales.discount * customers.annual_discount) 
   END  AS total_revenue FROM orderline_sales 
        JOIN
    orders_sales  ON orders_sales.id = orderline_sales.orders_sales_id
        JOIN
    employee ON orders_sales.empoyee_id = employee.id
        JOIN 
    customers ON orders_sales.customer_id = customers.id
   WHERE
      date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE
     GROUP BY employee.name
   ORDER BY totale_omzet DESC
```